# PrimeFaces SelectOneRadio

Tags: primefaces

I have one req , where I have a datable , which has x columns. One column contains 3 radio buttons .Which i am able to display . But my problem is I want one radio button to be selected by default .

What I am doing :  On Load of datatable i am creating one variable (also i tried with SlectIte   list)  , but unable to get checked value.

Can anyone provide a simple working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my demonstration which present how to default radio value in datatable

XHTML

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="catalog" value="#{radioView.catalogs}">
        <p:column headerText="City">
            <p:selectOneRadio id="city" 
                              value="#{catalog.city}"
                              columns="3">
                <f:selectItems value="#{radioView.cities}" 
                               var="c" 
                               itemLabel="#{city}" 
                               itemValue="#{city}"/>
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton value="changeSelection" 
                     process="@form" 
                     update="@form" 
                     actionListener="#{radioView.changeSelection}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="submit" 
                     process="@form" 
                     update="@form" 
                     actionListener="#{radioView.submit}"/>
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
public class RadioView {

    private List<Catalog> catalogs;
    private List<String> cities;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        cities.add("San Francisco");
        cities.add("London");
        cities.add("Paris");

        //default radio value
        Catalog c1 = new Catalog("San Francisco");
        Catalog c2 = new Catalog("London");
        Catalog c3 = new Catalog("Paris");
        Catalog c4 = new Catalog("London");

        catalogs = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
        catalogs.add(c1);
        catalogs.add(c2);
        catalogs.add(c3);
        catalogs.add(c4);
    }
    public List<Catalog> getCatalogs() {
        return catalogs;
    }
    public void setCatalogs(List<Catalog> catalogs) {
        this.catalogs = catalogs;
    }
    public List<String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
    public void changeSelection(ActionEvent event){
        for (Catalog catalog : catalogs) {
            catalog.setCity("San Francisco");
        }
    }
    public void submit(ActionEvent event) {
        for (Catalog catalog : catalogs) {
            System.out.println(catalog.getCity());
        }
    }
}
```

Domain

```
public class Catalog implements Serializable{

    private String city;
    public Catalog(String city){
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: @wttakam : Hi dear , I have tested ur example , but i m not seeing preselect city . And also i Used SelectItem ,, still not getting.

Comment: @wittakam: Extremely Srry dear , It's working , I did smthng wrong with ur example :(    Thx a lot , this helped me a lot.